# generate sympa wwsympa-wrapper.fcgi

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-22.04, sympa

As a beginner,
Will you have informations about installing sympa 6.2.66 web interface using sympa and the wwsympa.fgci ?
Or the web interface configuration after an upgrade from the 6.2.40 version ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Documentation of wwsympa is in sympa community site and is up to date.

You will find your answers there :
https://www.sympa.community/manual/install/configure-http-server.html

Sympa community can be contacted by its mailing list ( obviously ) https://www.sympa.community/community/lists.html

For ubuntu the layout of sympa is this of Debian and is described here : https://www.sympa.community/manual/layout.html